# Is the LED drop voltage difference between colors linked to the different wavelength energy?

Tags: led

To me appears that LEDs that emitt light with less energy (e.g. IR and red) have less voltage forward drop than the ones with more energy associated to their wavelength (such as blue or UV).

That would be fascinating.

Is this a true correlation or is it dependent solely on the technology available?

Comment: Yes. It is a true correlation. Note: some LED's may employ phosphors. If so, they may be, for example, UV LED's with phosphors in the lens. The color seen by the observer will be determined by the phosphors. But otherwise, yes, the photon energy and forward voltage are closely related.

Comment: Not only is it correct, you can use it to calculate Planck's constant!  Get a bunch of LEDs of known wavelengths.  Calculate their frequencies using *c=fλ*.  Measure their forward voltages.  Calculate the energy by multiplying by elementary charge: *E=Vq*.  Now plot *E* versus *f* and the slope will be Planck's constant, *h*.

Comment: @mkeith if what you say is true, why is it when an InGaN LED's wavelength shortens from deep blue to blue to cyan to green the energy carried by the photons decreases and Vf increases?

Comment: @DrSheldon You would have to measure the bandgap energy, compensate for thermal characteristics, then you'd have the total amount of energy.  You also need the spectral distribution, and the number of photons art each wavelength.  
See this link and try to calculate backwards from knowing only the total energy.   
https://www.berthold-bio.com/service-support/support-portal/knowledge-base/how-do-i-convert-irradiance-into-photon-flux.html
 -- I used the formulas from that link to create this page and tested with a spectrometer: http://www.growlightresearch.com/ppfd/convert.html

Comment: @Misunderstood: If you're working for NIST and want the most accurate value, yes.  If you're giving undergraduate students a laboratory experiment, then they usually get within 5-10% of the actual value.

Comment: @DrSheldon No, I'm saying even if given the photon energy released you could not get to Planck constant or Avogadro number.  What you said is not true for two reasons.  1) Vf does not give you photon energy.  2) you do not have the spectral distribution of the photons nor know the number of photons being emitted.   Try it.  Run the numbers with Vf, or better photon energy, and see that what you said is not possible without spectral distribution and photon count.

Comment: @Misunderstood: I think you're dividing *E* by *f*, which will not work.  Instead, you make a graph (each LED is one point on the graph).  It ends up being linear, and the slope is Planck's constant.  The effects you mention each *do affect the y-intercept of the graph*, but that is ignored.  My students have had good results for over a decade.

Comment: @DrSheldon what???  I'm not dividing anything by anything.  I'm saying what you said is WRONG!!!!!!!  Let's keep it simple answer this?  Why is it when a InGaN LED's wavelength shortens from deep blue to blue to cyan to green the energy carried by the photons decreases and yet Vf increases?  What wavelengths did your students use?

Comment: @Misunderstood, it will take me a long time to digest all you wrote in your answer. But if I look at your graph excerpted from the textbook, it sure looks like the bandgap energy and forward voltage are pretty well correlated, even if some of the AlGaInN points are above the trend line.

Comment: @mkeith that is kind of misleading.  Notice most of the materials begin with AlGa,  almost all aluminum gallium. Notice how green and blue are way off the slope.Most yellow through red are AlInGaP.   Notice there is no InGaN which is what is now commonly used for 450 nm through 530 nm (blue thru green).  The chart was made with data from two studies Krames 2000 and Emerson 2002.   My proof is in InGaN where deep blue=>blue=>cyan=>green respective Vf are: 2.90V=>2.95V=>3.17V=>2.21V.  Photon energy decrease from blue to green. Also I added the thing about the number of photons generated per watt

Comment: A misleading correlation, I guess. It would not be the first time.

Comment: So, in theory, in the future we could find better dopants that will give us less Vf for the shorter wavelengths?

Comment: That would be the holy grail if an LED with more efficient materials were found in the UVA to near UV spectrum.  These are the wavelengths that can make white phosphor pumped LEDs.  This is where the money is.  The Vf of white LED (deep blue) keeps decreasing.  One way increase efficacy (lumens/watt) is to reduce Vf. A lot of research ($$) is going into reducing the Vf or white LEDs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The energy level of photons is not the reason V<sub>f</sub> rises with the energy level of the photons.

Why?  Because that does not always happen.

Here is the 100 µmol energy level for four wavelengths of InGaN LEDs and their V<sub>f</sub>.

Notice how as the V<sub>f</sub> rises, the energy decreases.

[image]

Source V<sub>f</sub>: [Lumiled Rebel Color Datasheet](https://www.lumileds.com/uploads/265/DS68-pdf)
Source Energy: [How do I convert irradiance into photon flux?](https://www.berthold-bio.com/service-support/support-portal/knowledge-base/how-do-i-convert-irradiance-into-photon-flux.html)
and [Photometric, Radiometrtic, Quantum Conversions](http://www.growlightresearch.com/ppfd/convert.html)

---

A photon cannot be measured with a volt meter.
The photon and the energy it carries has been emitted from the LED.
So how could a photon's energy possibly be included in the  V<sub>f</sub> when it is off traveling at the speed of light away from the LED?

---

Photon energy does not directly contribute to V<sub>f</sub>.
The instantaneous resistivity of materials used are what determines V<sub>f</sub>

---

**More Energy = Less Photons**

This question is based on the fact that a longer wavelength photon carries less energy than a shorter wavelength photon.
A 660 nm deep red photon carries 66% as much energy as a deep blue photon.

But that is only part of the equation.

3.76 µmols of 450 nm deep blue photons will carry 1 watt of energy.
5.52 µmols of 660 nm deep  red photons will carry 1 watt of energy.

That's 56% more red photons than blue per watt.

It takes one electron to create 1 photon.
1 µmol = 602,214,076,000,000,000

So it's kind of a wash.
While blue carries more energy, less blue photons are generated per watt.
While  red carries less energy, more red photons are generated per watt.
Source: [Photometric, Radiometrtic, Quantum Conversions](http://www.growlightresearch.com/ppfd/convert.html)

---

Regarding the claim

> a certain voltage is required for the electrons to get them across
>   the depletion region. The electron releases its energy as a photon.
>   ...the bandgap of the material gives the
>   characteristic wavelength. Higher bandgaps give shorter wavelengths.

While the energy in the bandgap approximates the released optical energy,
 
the bandgap energy is not represented in V<sub>f</sub>

The bandgap energy approximates the released optical energy only if the LED's thermal characteristics are overlooked.
Source: [Light Emitting Diodes by E. Fred Schubert](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521865387)

---

If you were to go to Digikey and sort (ascending) white LEDs by V<sub>f</sub>
You will find in the adjacent column, the efficacy (lm/W), the LEDs with very high efficacy.  Then if you sort by efficacy (ascending) you will find higher  V<sub>f</sub>.

With more electrons being converted to photons (higher efficacy) there are less electrons that make it through the bandgap to the conduction band.  The electrons in the conduction band will add to the  V<sub>f</sub> whereas those converted to photons are not included in the  V<sub>f</sub>.

Answer (score 23):

> The wavelength range of commercially available LEDs with single-element output power of at least 5 mW is 360 to 950 nm. Each wavelength range is made from a specific semiconductor material family, regardless of the manufacturer. Source: [Photonics - Light-Emitting Diodes: A Primer](https://www.photonics.com/Articles/Light-Emitting_Diodes_A_Primer/a36706).

The article is worth a read.

[image]

*Figure 1. The LED color guide from [Lumex](http://lumex.com) gives a good overview of the various LED types, chemistry and wavelengths. For some explanation, if required, see [LEDs and colour](https://lednique.com/leds-and-colour/) (mine).*

Like all diodes (the D of LED), a certain voltage is required for the electrons to get them across the depletion region. The electron releases its energy as a photon. Your hunch is correct and the bandgap of the material gives the characteristic wavelength. Higher bandgaps give shorter wavelengths.

[image]

*Figure 2. The forward voltage drops vary with current. [What is an LED?](https://lednique.com/what-is-an-led/).*

This data for this graph was taken from various datasheets and carefully plotted. The LEDs, however, were from different manufacturers and there is some variation in the forward voltages.

White LEDs, for example, are 450nm deep blue LEDs covered with wavelength converting phosphors. When a deep blue photon is absorbed by the phosphor it is reemitted at a longer wavelength (e.g. blue-cyan-green-red). So the white IV curve will be the same as the deep blue curve within the same product line.   I'm still working on this.

Comment: While the following text is true, the energy in the bandgap is not represented in the forward voltage.  Vf is a result of the resistivity of the n,p and dopants.   THIS IS TRUE, BUT...: Your hunch is correct and the bandgap of the material gives the characteristic wavelength. Higher bandgaps give shorter wavelengths.

Answer (score 12):

It's linked, with some details that mean you can't draw a straight line through all the points.

The energy needed to create a photon of any particular wavelength sets the absolute minimum Vf that a diode requires when running. In addition to that, there are further small voltage drops dependent on the particular technology, the particular materials that go to make a particular bandgap semiconductor.

IIRC, yellow and green require a very similar voltage, which is probably technology dependent. But generally, red and IR do require less, and blue and UV more, due to photon energy requirement.

Comment: Can you add in some detail on what might be included in the technology dependency? As mentioned in my answer, I'm having trouble getting good data for my LED IV curves. There are differences in LEDs from different manufacturers and as a result my yellow curve appears to have higher voltage than the green whereas one might expect it to lie between orange and green.

Comment: @Transistor the fact that a diode is 3 junctions, two with metal to semi, and only one with semi to semi, means that the metal to semi junctions are going to have an influence on total forward voltage. I was shooting from the hip there, trying to recall results from way back, but from your results it looks like I was spot on with the yellow/green thing. I did wonder whether to mention argon/potassium, as where the periodic table generally follows atomic weights, except for a few places where it doesn't, but it's not too helpful.

Comment: @Transistor The photon energy has little to do with Vf. Wire bonding has nothing  to do with Vf.  The forward voltage is more electron related than photon. With greater efficacy (photons per watt) there are fewer electrons in the bandgap as more electrons have been converted to electrons. Once an electron becomes a photon it's electrical energy can no longer be measured. Less electrons means lower voltage, lower voltage means lower thermal power generated (electrical converted) and therefore higher efficacy.  The rest is the width of the bandgap and the energy required to cross it.

Comment: @Neil: I hadn't considered the metal to semi junctions. I don't think it was mentioned in my studies, many decades ago, nor in my reading of the hobby electronics magazines. I'll follow up on that. Thank you.

Comment: @Transistor sure the bond and wire will have resistance but it is minimal (mOhms) and it is the same amount of resistance across all colors within the same product line.   Just as the resistance of the heterostructures, and bulk resistance of the materials adds to internal serial and parallel resistances but not related to wavelength energy.  But heterostructures, and bulk resistance are very much related to Vf.

Comment: @Mis: Thank you. I'll do some research. The "same product line" was the problem I was having with generating the graph. I can't find any manufacturers offering a product line that covers a large part of the spectrum - never mind all of it. That made comparing like with like impossible. I have been gathering my thoughts together to post a question on the topic.

Comment: @Transistor Lumiled (Rebel Color, Color C) , Cree (XPE), and OSRAM (Oslon SSL) have colors from 450 nm deep blue to 660 nm deep red.  Lumiled and Cree  have 740nm far red as well.  I design LED lighting for horticulture photo chemical research,  so have to be familiar with all the colors.

Comment: Your answer appears correct when you look at AlInGaP in the IR-red wavelengths LEDs.  Your answer falls apart if you were to look at InGaN (UV-green)  LEDs.  As InGaN wavelengths get longer (less energy carried by photons) Vf increases.

Comment: @Misunderstood While I bow to your superior experience, I think the general thrust of the answer, it's true(ish), is as useful in terms of ideas per paragraph as yours. Higher photon energy requires larger bandgap requires higher voltage, in general. I try to answer to the apparent level of the OP's question. I'm interested in the LXML- red and red/orange. What's the mechanism for their relatively higher voltage?

Comment: The difference is the LXML are the early release in the Rebel line.  As Lumiled made advances in technology they would add a 1,2,3,4,5 to LXML. ---  I have been working on my answer for the past 5-6 hours due to fact checking.  I just added more on the bandgap energy and the effect on Vf vs the resistivity of the materials.  And not done yet.  Next is the efficiency of the material which will explain why what you presume is not true.